# Angular2 hide show elements based on multiple condition smart way

Tags: angular

I have 10-12 buttons and other few inputs on my page.
depends on users and user types I need to show and hide buttons and inputs.

for example

if user=a then hide 3 buttons and 2 inputs.
if user=b and userType=mgr then hide other 2 buttons and other inputs
etc....

How would I smartly handle these conditions?

Should I write if condition on all the buttons and inputs? Different templates? something I can handle at component side and use it in html?

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I would build methods at Component level to encapsulate the logic that drives visibility and combine them with *ngIf or [hidden].

In other words:

- for each button, input (or other html element) that needs to be shown
  or hidden based on logic create a method like `showElementXXX() : boolean`
- then add the show/hide control switch in the template, e.g.

I hope this helps